# Появляется горизонтальная прокрутка при просмотре через инструменты разработчика((

Tags: html, css

Проблема не уходит, даже если боди оставить пустым((

```css
* {
  font-family: "Manrope", sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #000000;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

input,
button,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

@mixin main__button() {
  background: #f57059;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 17px 35px;
}

.button__link {
  @include main__button();
  color: #ffffff;
}

.button__link:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #f57059;
}

.header {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 120px;
  position: relative;
}

.header .figure {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-top: -68px;
  margin-left: -141px;
  max-width: 900px;
  max-height: 820px;
}

.header .nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.header .nav__logo {
  font-family: "Gilroy", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header .nav__list {
  display: flex;
  gap: 40px;
  align-items: center;
}

.header .nav__button {
  display: flex;
  gap: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}

.header .nav__item,
.header .nav__button,
.header .nav .dropdown-content {
  font-family: "Manrope";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 19px;
}

.header .nav__after {
  position: relative;
}

.header .nav__after::after,
.header .nav__after::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.header .nav__after::after {
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid #000000;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 6px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header .nav__after::before {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #ffebcd;
  right: -18px;
  bottom: 9px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.header .nav .dropbtn {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header .nav .dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header .nav .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header .nav .dropdown-content a {
  padding: 10px 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5%;
}

.header .nav .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #000000;
}

.header .nav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <picture class="figure">
        <source srcset="images/first__block/first__block__bg.png" media="screen and (max-width: 1200px)">
        <img src="images/first__block/first__block__bg.png" alt="figure">
      </picture>
      <nav class="nav">
        <span class="nav__logo">AR Shakir</span>
        <div class="nav__list">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="nav__item nav__after dropbtn">Product</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="nav__item nav__after dropbtn">Template</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="nav__item">Blog</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav__item">Pricing</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav__button">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="button__sign">Sign In</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="button__link">Start Free</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Это появляется только тогда, когда вы открываете инструменты разработчика? Это же нормальное явление, а если хотите убрать, то напишите свойство overflow: hidden; элементу body

Comment: Когда начинается появляться скролл? Я вижу только на `< 493px`, но там логично, элементы шире вьюпорта.

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  font-family: "Manrope", sans-serif;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #000000;
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li {
  list-style: none;
}

input,
button,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
}

@mixin main__button() {
  background: #f57059;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 17px 35px;
}

.button__link {
  @include main__button();
  color: #ffffff;
}

.button__link:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px #f57059;
}

.header {
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 120px;
  position: relative;
}

.header .figure {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-top: -68px;
  margin-left: -141px;
  max-width: 900px;
  max-height: 820px;
}

.header .nav {
 display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.header .nav__logo {
  font-family: "Gilroy", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header .nav__list {
  display: flex;
  gap: 40px;
  align-items: center;
}

.header .nav__button {
  display: flex;
  gap: 50px;
  align-items: center;
}

.header .nav__item,
.header .nav__button,
.header .nav .dropdown-content {
  font-family: "Manrope";
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 19px;
}

.header .nav__after {
  position: relative;
}

.header .nav__after::after,
.header .nav__after::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.header .nav__after::after {
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  border-top: 6px solid #000000;
  right: -20px;
  bottom: 6px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header .nav__after::before {
  border-left: 4px solid transparent;
  border-right: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid #ffebcd;
  right: -18px;
  bottom: 9px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.header .nav .dropbtn {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.header .nav .dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.header .nav .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.header .nav .dropdown-content a {
  padding: 10px 0 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 5%;
}

.header .nav .dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  text-shadow: 0 0 20px #000000;
}

.header .nav .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="container">
      <picture class="figure">
        <source srcset="images/first__block/first__block__bg.png" media="screen and (max-width: 1200px)">
        <img src="images/first__block/first__block__bg.png" alt="figure">
      </picture>
      <nav class="nav">
        <span class="nav__logo">AR Shakir</span>
        <div class="nav__list">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="nav__item nav__after dropbtn">Product</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="nav__item nav__after dropbtn">Template</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#">Link 1</a>
              <a href="#">Link 2</a>
              <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <a href="#" class="nav__item">Blog</a>
          <a href="#" class="nav__item">Pricing</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav__button">
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="button__sign">Sign In</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#" class="button__link">Start Free</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: Напишите, пожалуйста, текстом что сделали :)

Comment: @gil9red обернул флекс и выставил блоки в строку

Comment: @gil9red здесь `.header .nav`

Comment: Это лучше в самом вопросе писать :)